# Polymer: --paper-item-selected-weight not working

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to apply a background color but not bold the `paper-item` when its selected. I notice the weight property does not do anything ...

```
paper-item {    
  --paper-item-selected-weight: normal; /* its still bold */ 

  --paper-item-selected: {
    background: #3f9c35; /* no issues here */
  }
}
```

The HTML

```
<paper-menu selected="0">
  <paper-item>TEST</paper-item>
```

The same happens if I use `paper-icon-item`

Comment: Are you styling inside `<dom-module>` or in `custom-style`? Please update answer with more complete example

Comment: I've try to reproduce, assuming you were styling inside dom-module it's perfectly working. So can you please provide a complete non working sample like Tomasz said ? Thanks